# Handle two radio buttons in a table layout

Tags: android-layout, android

In a table layout, there are two radio buttons in two rows. Is there any way to tie them as a group (as in radio group)? That means, user can check only one radio button at a time.

I tried to handle the logic at the event invocation using listener interfaces.

Any thoughts on a better way around?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think here is the perfect example for you.
>>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381560/how-to-group-a-3x3-grid-of-radio-buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener) on the radio buttons. When you get call in one radio button then uncheck other radio buttons.....