# Arrange12 RadioButtons in a 4*3 grid

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I wish to arrange 12 RadioButtons in a 4*3 grid.
All the RadioButtons must be in one RadioGroup.

Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [How to group a 3x3 grid of radio buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381560/how-to-group-a-3x3-grid-of-radio-buttons)

Maybe this could solve your problem, otherwise I wouldn't recommend RadioButtons. Customized Buttons "could" also work in this situation...