# How to group RadioButton from different LinearLayouts?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-linearlayout, radio-group

I was wondering if is possible to group each single `RadioButton` in a unique `RadioGroup`
maintaining the same structure. My structure look like this:

- LinearLayout_main

  - LinearLayout_1

    - RadioButton1
  - LinearLayout_2

    - RadioButton2
  - LinearLayout_3

    - RadioButton3

As you can see, now each `RadioButton` is a child of different `LinearLayout`. I tried using the structure below, but it doesn't work:

- Radiogroup

  - LinearLayout_main

    - LinearLayout_1

      - RadioButton1
    - LinearLayout_2

      - RadioButton2
    - LinearLayout_3

      - RadioButton3

Comment: @coding crow, if you're forced to ask then you've never worked with a designer for UI flow (and I'm guessing your radio buttons probably aren't very sophisticated).  Imagine (if you can) a radio button that sits next to two pieces of text, one that is a headline and one that is a subtext. Now imagine 5 of these on top of one another. How do you accomplish that? Ah right... you can't.  It's a good thing that nothing so fancy was ever needed or google would really look foolish having overlooked such basic layout functionality in their otherwise comprehensive layout toolset.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel wow, although I agree with what u say (usage of radioButtons), but maybe your reaction was too emotional? :)

Comment: It wasn't emotional so much as clearly annoyed.  What does that comment offer to the OP? What does it offer to the thread in general? It implies that the question is without merit and is impatient and snarky.  If he had started it with "Could you please explain why you would want to do this" that would be both appropriate and polite. "I am forced to ask" is a thinly veiled alternative to "what sort of idiot would need this wacky kluge?". At least that's how I read it.

Comment: It's been three years, and still no accepted answer?

Comment: Why android dev still don't allow to use LinearLayout inside RadioGroup? 
Marshmallow has been released.

Comment: Still no proper answer? I was searching for a solution

Comment: reading Gaurav Agawal's comment, I think there should be facility to downvote a comment

Answer (score 57):

It seems that the good people at Google/Android assume that when you use RadioButtons, you don't need the flexibility that comes with every other aspect of the Android UI/layout system. To put it simply: they don't want you to nest layouts and radio buttons.  Sigh.

So you gotta work around the problem. That means you must implement radio buttons on your own.

This really isn't too hard.  In your onCreate(), set your RadioButtons with their own onClick() so that when they are activated, they setChecked(true) and do the opposite for the other buttons.  For example:

```
class FooActivity {

    RadioButton m_one, m_two, m_three;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        m_one = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.first_radio_button);
        m_two = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.second_radio_button);
        m_three = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.third_radio_button);

        m_one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                m_one.setChecked(true);
                m_two.setChecked(false);
                m_three.setChecked(false);
            }
        });

        m_two.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                m_one.setChecked(false);
                m_two.setChecked(true);
                m_three.setChecked(false);
            }
        });

        m_three.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                m_one.setChecked(false);
                m_two.setChecked(false);
                m_three.setChecked(true);
            }
        });

        ...     
    } // onCreate() 

}
```

Yeah, I know--way old-school. But it works. Good luck!

Comment: infuriating. simply unbelievable that this is the level of klugery necessary to do something as mundane as a "radio button". It's beyond belief that Google hands us so many short cuts for things that are almost entirely useless (like 80% of the Animations widgetry) and then leaves us to spackle together our own radio buttons. (spit!).

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: Yeah, I agree that a *lot* of their UI choices are bizarre.  My only guess about this limitation is they may be thinking, "It's really not that hard to do it manually."  But it would have been nice if they documented this lack of feature at least a little bit (like a tutorial page?). As you point out, they've gone waaaay overboard on other nearly useless things (pet projects, perhaps?).

Comment: I can only guess, but my overall impression is that Android's UI team is either given short shrift or is just generally fairly weak.  Consider what passes for "elegant" in the google universe. It's all really spartan and utilitarian.  I'm not a fan of Apple because I prefer functionality to style, but if ever a mega-company with hordes of cash needed to rethink its look and feel (up and down the chain) I can't think of a better candidate than Google.

Comment: This is by far one of the most reliable and simple solutions there is... although prehistoric, it's a shame Google has not implemented something more efficient...

Comment: Beautiful, simple implementation.

Comment: Yeah .. I was expecting something like manually assigning radio button IDs to the RadioGroup or something would exist if it's costly to be automatic traversal on extra view groups that don't contain radio buttons within the radio group.. I was so sure something like this exists so I started searching. I now leave this post in despair.

Comment: Don't confuse OnClickListener with OnCheckedChangeListener. The later won't work since it will invoke itself as many times as you cal setChecked() on each radio button.

Comment: It sucks that RadioGroup inherits LinearLayout.... We really need one with ConstraintLayout or other layouts that are more flexible. We are in 2018! Making customized RadioGrouped view is still a f- tedious job to do.

Comment: Ten years after, the Good people are still .....  Thanks @SMBiggs for the help. I'm using Relative Layout and my users were complaining. Now I have this solution

Answer (score 29):

Use this class that I created. It will find all checkable children in your hierarchy.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyRadioGroup extends LinearLayout {

private ArrayList<View> mCheckables = new ArrayList<View>();

public MyRadioGroup(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyRadioGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public MyRadioGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void addView(View child, int index,
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, index, params);
    parseChild(child);
}

public void parseChild(final View child)
{
    if(child instanceof Checkable)
    {
        mCheckables.add(child);
        child.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i = 0; i < mCheckables.size();i++)
                {
                    Checkable view = (Checkable) mCheckables.get(i);
                    if(view == v)
                    {
                        ((Checkable)view).setChecked(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((Checkable)view).setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else if(child instanceof ViewGroup)
    {
        parseChildren((ViewGroup)child);
    }
}

public void parseChildren(final ViewGroup child)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < child.getChildCount();i++)
    {
        parseChild(child.getChildAt(i));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: given this code, how would i get the current selected button ?

Comment: i just put in a variable mCheckedview when you set the  ((Checkable)view).setChecked(true); and i return that variable when i need to know which one was checked. seems ok now but have to "performClick()"on default one i want. thanks

Answer (score 17):

Well, I wrote this simple class.

Just use it like this:

```
// add any number of RadioButton resource IDs here
GRadioGroup gr = new GRadioGroup(this, 
    R.id.radioButton1, R.id.radioButton2, R.id.radioButton3);
```

or

```
GRadioGroup gr = new GRadioGroup(rb1, rb2, rb3);
// where RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
// etc.
```

You can call it in onCreate() of Activity for example. No matter which `RadioButton` you click, the others will become unchecked. Also, no matters, if some of `RadioButtons` are inside of some `RadioGroup`, or not.

Here's the class:

```
package pl.infografnet.GClasses;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class GRadioGroup {

    List<RadioButton> radios = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();

    /**
     * Constructor, which allows you to pass number of RadioButton instances,
     * making a group.
     * 
     * @param radios
     *            One RadioButton or more.
     */
    public GRadioGroup(RadioButton... radios) {
        super();

        for (RadioButton rb : radios) {
            this.radios.add(rb);
            rb.setOnClickListener(onClick);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor, which allows you to pass number of RadioButtons 
     * represented by resource IDs, making a group.
     * 
     * @param activity
     *            Current View (or Activity) to which those RadioButtons 
     *            belong.
     * @param radiosIDs
     *            One RadioButton or more.
     */
    public GRadioGroup(View activity, int... radiosIDs) {
        super();

        for (int radioButtonID : radiosIDs) {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)activity.findViewById(radioButtonID);
            if (rb != null) {
                this.radios.add(rb);
                rb.setOnClickListener(onClick);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This occurs everytime when one of RadioButtons is clicked, 
     * and deselects all others in the group.
     */
    OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // let's deselect all radios in group
            for (RadioButton rb : radios) {

                ViewParent p = rb.getParent();
                if (p.getClass().equals(RadioGroup.class)) {
                    // if RadioButton belongs to RadioGroup, 
                    // then deselect all radios in it 
                    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) p;
                    rg.clearCheck();
                } else {
                    // if RadioButton DOES NOT belong to RadioGroup, 
                    // just deselect it
                    rb.setChecked(false);
                }
            }

            // now let's select currently clicked RadioButton
            if (v.getClass().equals(RadioButton.class)) {
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
                rb.setChecked(true);
            }

        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Nice. If you replace RadioButton with the super class CompoundButton then it's even better, as you can then add any toggleable buttons (such as ToggleButton) to the group!

Comment: It's worth noting that performing getCheckedRadioButtonId() from your regular radio group will no longer work (always returns -1) if the radio buttons are not directly nested in the radio group.  I added another method to the class above as follows:
`    /** 
     * Returns the Id of the radio button that is checked or -1 if none are checked
     * @return
     */
 public int getCheckedRadioButtonId() {
  int checkedId = -1;
  
  // Loop each radio button
  for (RadioButton rb : radios) {
   if (rb.isChecked()) {
    return rb.getId();
   }
  }
  return checkedId;
 }`

Answer (score 16):

Here's my solution based on [@lostdev solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461005/how-to-group-radiobutton-from-different-linearlayouts/14309274#14309274) and implementation of `RadioGroup`. It's a RadioGroup modified to work with RadioButtons (or other CompoundButtons) that are nested inside child layouts.

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * This class is a replacement for android RadioGroup - it supports
 * child layouts which standard RadioGroup doesn't.
 */
public class RecursiveRadioGroup extends LinearLayout {

    public interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
        void onCheckedChanged(RecursiveRadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId);
    }

    /**
     * For generating unique view IDs on API < 17 with {@link #generateViewId()}.
     */
    private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);

    private CompoundButton checkedView;

    private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener childOnCheckedChangeListener;

    /**
     * When this flag is true, onCheckedChangeListener discards events.
     */
    private boolean mProtectFromCheckedChange = false;

    private OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener;

    private PassThroughHierarchyChangeListener mPassThroughListener;

    public RecursiveRadioGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
        init();
    }

    public RecursiveRadioGroup(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public RecursiveRadioGroup(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        childOnCheckedChangeListener = new CheckedStateTracker();
        mPassThroughListener = new PassThroughHierarchyChangeListener();

        super.setOnHierarchyChangeListener(mPassThroughListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnHierarchyChangeListener(OnHierarchyChangeListener listener) {
        mPassThroughListener.mOnHierarchyChangeListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        // checks the appropriate radio button as requested in the XML file
        if (checkedView != null) {
            mProtectFromCheckedChange = true;
            setCheckedStateForView(checkedView, true);
            mProtectFromCheckedChange = false;
            setCheckedView(checkedView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        parseChild(child);

        super.addView(child, index, params);
    }

    private void parseChild(final View child) {
        if (child instanceof CompoundButton) {
            final CompoundButton checkable = (CompoundButton) child;

            if (checkable.isChecked()) {
                mProtectFromCheckedChange = true;
                if (checkedView != null) {
                    setCheckedStateForView(checkedView, false);
                }
                mProtectFromCheckedChange = false;
                setCheckedView(checkable);
            }
        } else if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            parseChildren((ViewGroup) child);
        }
    }

    private void parseChildren(final ViewGroup child) {
        for (int i = 0; i < child.getChildCount(); i++) {
            parseChild(child.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * <p>Sets the selection to the radio button whose identifier is passed in
     * parameter. Using -1 as the selection identifier clears the selection;
     * such an operation is equivalent to invoking {@link #clearCheck()}.</p>
     *
     * @param view the radio button to select in this group
     * @see #getCheckedItemId()
     * @see #clearCheck()
     */
    public void check(CompoundButton view) {
        if(checkedView != null) {
            setCheckedStateForView(checkedView, false);
        }

        if(view != null) {
            setCheckedStateForView(view, true);
        }

        setCheckedView(view);
    }

    private void setCheckedView(CompoundButton view) {
        checkedView = view;

        if(onCheckedChangeListener != null) {
            onCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(this, checkedView.getId());
        }
    }

    private void setCheckedStateForView(View checkedView, boolean checked) {
        if (checkedView != null && checkedView instanceof CompoundButton) {
            ((CompoundButton) checkedView).setChecked(checked);
        }
    }

    /**
     * <p>Returns the identifier of the selected radio button in this group.
     * Upon empty selection, the returned value is -1.</p>
     *
     * @return the unique id of the selected radio button in this group
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#RadioGroup_checkedButton
     * @see #check(CompoundButton)
     * @see #clearCheck()
     */
    @IdRes
    public int getCheckedItemId() {
        return checkedView.getId();
    }

    public CompoundButton getCheckedItem() {
        return checkedView;
    }

    /**
     * <p>Clears the selection. When the selection is cleared, no radio button
     * in this group is selected and {@link #getCheckedItemId()} returns
     * null.</p>
     *
     * @see #check(CompoundButton)
     * @see #getCheckedItemId()
     */
    public void clearCheck() {
        check(null);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Register a callback to be invoked when the checked radio button
     * changes in this group.</p>
     *
     * @param listener the callback to call on checked state change
     */
    public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(RecursiveRadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
        onCheckedChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Generate a value suitable for use in {@link #setId(int)}.
     * This value will not collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for R.id.
     *
     * @return a generated ID value
     */
    public static int generateViewId() {
        for (; ; ) {
            final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
            // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
            int newValue = result + 1;
            if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
            if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    private class CheckedStateTracker implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean b) {
            if (mProtectFromCheckedChange) {
                return;
            }

            mProtectFromCheckedChange = true;
            if (checkedView != null) {
                setCheckedStateForView(checkedView, false);
            }
            mProtectFromCheckedChange = false;

            int id = view.getId();
            setCheckedView(view);
        }
    }

    private class PassThroughHierarchyChangeListener implements OnHierarchyChangeListener {

        private OnHierarchyChangeListener mOnHierarchyChangeListener;

        @Override
        public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
            if (child instanceof CompoundButton) {
                int id = child.getId();

                if (id == View.NO_ID) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                        child.setId(generateViewId());
                    } else {
                        child.setId(View.generateViewId());
                    }
                }

                ((CompoundButton) child).setOnCheckedChangeListener(childOnCheckedChangeListener);

                if (mOnHierarchyChangeListener != null) {
                    mOnHierarchyChangeListener.onChildViewAdded(parent, child);
                }
            } else if(child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                // View hierarchy seems to be constructed from the bottom up,
                // so all child views are already added. That's why we
                // manually call the listener for all children of ViewGroup.
                for(int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) child).getChildCount(); i++) {
                    onChildViewAdded(child, ((ViewGroup) child).getChildAt(i));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {
            if (child instanceof RadioButton) {
                ((CompoundButton) child).setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            }

            if (mOnHierarchyChangeListener != null) {
                mOnHierarchyChangeListener.onChildViewRemoved(parent, child);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You can use it in your layout the same way as you would a regular `RadioGroup` with the exception that it works with nested `RadioButton` views as well:

```xml
<RecursiveRadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbNotEnoughProfileInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Not enough profile information"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbNotAGoodFit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Not a good fit"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbDatesNoLongerAvailable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dates no longer available"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbOther"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Other"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/etReason"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvMessageError"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:hint="Tell us more"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_multiline_background"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RecursiveRadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 10):

This solution has not been posted so posting :

Step 0: Create a `CompoundButton previousCheckedCompoundButton;` as global variable.

Step 1: Create `OnCheckedChangedListener` for radio buttons

```
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener onRadioButtonCheckedListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (!isChecked) return;
            if (previousCheckedCompoundButton != null) {
                previousCheckedCompoundButton.setChecked(false);
            } 
            previousCheckedCompoundButton = buttonView;
        }
    };
```

Step 3: add listener to all radio buttons:

```
radioButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
radioButton2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
radioButton3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
radioButton4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
```

Thats it!! your'e done.

Answer (score 8):

Sigh.. Really blame that Android lacks such a basic functionality.

Adapted from @ScottBiggs answer, here's the possibly shortest way to do it with Kotlin:

```
var currentSelected = button1
listOf<RadioButton>(
    button1, button2, button3, ...
).forEach {
    it.setOnClickListener { _ ->
        currentSelected.isChecked = false
        currentSelected = it
        currentSelected.isChecked = true
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no logic inside your answer
check it more carefully

Comment: @EdgarKhimich what do you mean by "no logic"..? my code simply and elegantly answers the original question of how to group a number of radio buttons. we are not setting any other onclicklistener than a simple check toggling.

Comment: This is perfect...works like a charm, and doesn't add much code.Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use this simple RadioGroup extension code. Drop whatever layouts/views/images in it along with the RadioButtons and it will work.

It contains selection callback which returns the selected RadioButton with its index and you can set selection programatically by index or id:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EnhancedRadioGroup extends RadioGroup implements View.OnClickListener {

    public interface OnSelectionChangedListener {
        void onSelectionChanged(RadioButton radioButton, int index);
    }

    private OnSelectionChangedListener selectionChangedListener;
    ArrayList<RadioButton> radioButtons = new ArrayList<>();

    public EnhancedRadioGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EnhancedRadioGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        if (changed) {
            getRadioButtons();
        }
    }

    private void getRadioButtons() {
        radioButtons.clear();
        checkForRadioButtons(this);
    }

    private void checkForRadioButtons(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (viewGroup == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof RadioButton) {
                v.setOnClickListener(this);
                // store index of item
                v.setTag(radioButtons.size());
                radioButtons.add((RadioButton) v);
            }
            else if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
                checkForRadioButtons((ViewGroup)v);
            }
        }
    }

    public RadioButton getSelectedItem() {
        if (radioButtons.isEmpty()) {
            getRadioButtons();
        }
        for (RadioButton radioButton : radioButtons) {
            if (radioButton.isChecked()) {
                return radioButton;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setOnSelectionChanged(OnSelectionChangedListener selectionChangedListener) {
        this.selectionChangedListener = selectionChangedListener;
    }

    public void setSelectedById(int id) {
        if (radioButtons.isEmpty()) {
            getRadioButtons();
        }
        for (RadioButton radioButton : radioButtons) {
            boolean isSelectedRadioButton = radioButton.getId() == id;
            radioButton.setChecked(isSelectedRadioButton);
            if (isSelectedRadioButton && selectionChangedListener != null) {
                selectionChangedListener.onSelectionChanged(radioButton, (int)radioButton.getTag());
            }
        }
    }

    public void setSelectedByIndex(int index) {
        if (radioButtons.isEmpty()) {
            getRadioButtons();
        }
        if (radioButtons.size() > index) {
            setSelectedRadioButton(radioButtons.get(index));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setSelectedRadioButton((RadioButton) v);
    }

    private void setSelectedRadioButton(RadioButton rb) {
        if (radioButtons.isEmpty()) {
            getRadioButtons();
        }
        for (RadioButton radioButton : radioButtons) {
            radioButton.setChecked(rb == radioButton);
        }
        if (selectionChangedListener != null) {
            selectionChangedListener.onSelectionChanged(rb, (int)rb.getTag());
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in you layout xml:

```
    <path.to.your.package.EnhancedRadioGroup>
       Layouts containing RadioButtons/Images/Views and other RadioButtons
    </path.to.your.package.EnhancedRadioGroup>
```

To register to the callback:

```
        enhancedRadioGroupInstance.setOnSelectionChanged(new EnhancedRadioGroup.OnSelectionChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectionChanged(RadioButton radioButton, int index) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

I created these two methods to solve this problem. All you have to do is pass the ViewGroup where the RadioButtons are (could be a RadioGroup, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.) and it sets the OnClick events exclusively, that is, whenever one of the RadioButtons that is a child of the ViewGroup (at any nested level) is selected, the others are unselected. It works with as many nested layouts as you would like.

```
public class Utils {
    public static void setRadioExclusiveClick(ViewGroup parent) {
        final List<RadioButton> radios = getRadioButtons(parent);

        for (RadioButton radio: radios) {
            radio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    RadioButton r = (RadioButton) v;
                    r.setChecked(true);
                    for (RadioButton r2:radios) {
                        if (r2.getId() != r.getId()) {
                            r2.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static List<RadioButton> getRadioButtons(ViewGroup parent) {
        List<RadioButton> radios = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
        for (int i=0;i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof RadioButton) {
                radios.add((RadioButton) v);
            } else if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
                List<RadioButton> nestedRadios = getRadioButtons((ViewGroup) v);
                radios.addAll(nestedRadios);
            }
        }
        return radios;
    }
}
```

Usage inside an activity would be like this:

```
ViewGroup parent = findViewById(R.id.radios_parent);
Utils.setRadioExclusiveClick(parent);
```

Comment: more useful than all others solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've written my own radio group class that allows to contain nested radio buttons. Check it out. If you find bugs, please let me know.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * This class is used to create a multiple-exclusion scope for a set of compound
 * buttons. Checking one compound button that belongs to a group unchecks any
 * previously checked compound button within the same group. Intially, all of
 * the compound buttons are unchecked. While it is not possible to uncheck a
 * particular compound button, the group can be cleared to remove the checked
 * state. Basically, this class extends functionality of
 * {@link android.widget.RadioGroup} because it doesn't require that compound
 * buttons are direct childs of the group. This means you can wrap compound
 * buttons with other views. <br>
 * <br>
 * 
 * <b>IMPORTATNT! Follow these instruction when using this class:</b><br>
 * 1. Each direct child of this group must contain one compound button or be
 * compound button itself.<br>
 * 2. Do not set any "on click" or "on checked changed" listeners for the childs
 * of this group.
 */
public class CompoundButtonsGroup extends LinearLayout {

 private View checkedView;
 private OnCheckedChangeListener listener;
 private OnHierarchyChangeListener onHierarchyChangeListener;

 private OnHierarchyChangeListener onHierarchyChangeListenerInternal = new OnHierarchyChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public final void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
   notifyHierarchyChanged(null);
   if (CompoundButtonsGroup.this.onHierarchyChangeListener != null) {
    CompoundButtonsGroup.this.onHierarchyChangeListener.onChildViewAdded(
      parent, child);
   }
  }

  @Override
  public final void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {
   notifyHierarchyChanged(child);
   if (CompoundButtonsGroup.this.onHierarchyChangeListener != null) {
    CompoundButtonsGroup.this.onHierarchyChangeListener.onChildViewRemoved(
      parent, child);
   }
  }
 };

 public CompoundButtonsGroup(Context context) {
  super(context);
  init();
 }

 public CompoundButtonsGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  init();
 }

 public CompoundButtonsGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  init();
 }

 private void init() {
  super.setOnHierarchyChangeListener(this.onHierarchyChangeListenerInternal);
 }

 @Override
 public final void setOnHierarchyChangeListener(OnHierarchyChangeListener listener) {
  this.onHierarchyChangeListener = listener;
 }

 /**
  * Register a callback to be invoked when the checked view changes in this
  * group.
  * 
  * @param listener
  *            the callback to call on checked state change.
  */
 public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
  this.listener = listener;
 }

 /**
  * Returns currently selected view in this group. Upon empty selection, the
  * returned value is null.
  */
 public View getCheckedView() {
  return this.checkedView;
 }

 /**
  * Returns index of currently selected view in this group. Upon empty
  * selection, the returned value is -1.
  */
 public int getCheckedViewIndex() {
  return (this.checkedView != null) ? indexOfChild(this.checkedView) : -1;
 }

 /**
  * Sets the selection to the view whose index in group is passed in
  * parameter.
  * 
  * @param index
  *            the index of the view to select in this group.
  */
 public void check(int index) {
  check(getChildAt(index));
 }

 /**
  * Clears the selection. When the selection is cleared, no view in this
  * group is selected and {@link #getCheckedView()} returns null.
  */
 public void clearCheck() {
  if (this.checkedView != null) {
   findCompoundButton(this.checkedView).setChecked(false);
   this.checkedView = null;
   onCheckedChanged();
  }
 }

 private void onCheckedChanged() {
  if (this.listener != null) {
   this.listener.onCheckedChanged(this.checkedView);
  }
 }

 private void check(View child) {
  if (this.checkedView == null || !this.checkedView.equals(child)) {
   if (this.checkedView != null) {
    findCompoundButton(this.checkedView).setChecked(false);
   }

   CompoundButton comBtn = findCompoundButton(child);
   comBtn.setChecked(true);

   this.checkedView = child;
   onCheckedChanged();
  }
 }

 private void notifyHierarchyChanged(View removedView) {
  for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
   View child = getChildAt(i);
   child.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     check(v);
    }
   });
   CompoundButton comBtn = findCompoundButton(child);
   comBtn.setClickable(comBtn.equals(child));
  }

  if (this.checkedView != null && removedView != null
    && this.checkedView.equals(removedView)) {
   clearCheck();
  }
 }

 private CompoundButton findCompoundButton(View view) {
  if (view instanceof CompoundButton) {
   return (CompoundButton) view;
  }

  if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
   for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
    CompoundButton compoundBtn = findCompoundButton(((ViewGroup) view)
      .getChildAt(i));
    if (compoundBtn != null) {
     return compoundBtn;
    }
   }
  }

  return null;
 }

 /**
  * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the checked view
  * changed in this group.
  */
 public interface OnCheckedChangeListener {

  /**
   * Called when the checked view has changed.
   * 
   * @param checkedView
   *            newly checked view or null if selection was cleared in the
   *            group.
   */
  public void onCheckedChanged(View checkedView);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things:

1. Use `mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`
2. Make your custom row view implement `Checkable`.

So I think that the better solution is to implement Checkable inside your inner LinearLayout: (thanks to daichan4649, from his link, https://gist.github.com/daichan4649/5245378, I took all the code pasted below)

CheckableLayout.java

```
package daichan4649.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class CheckableLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {

    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = { android.R.attr.state_checked };

    public CheckableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    public CheckableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CheckableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private boolean checked;

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (this.checked != checked) {
            this.checked = checked;
            refreshDrawableState();

            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                if (child instanceof Checkable) {
                    ((Checkable) child).setChecked(checked);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!checked);
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }
}
```

inflater_list_column.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<daichan4649.test.CheckableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/check_area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</daichan4649.test.CheckableLayout>
```

TestFragment.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);

    // 表示データ
    List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // 初期選択位置
    int initSelectedPosition = 3;

    // リスト設定
    TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(getActivity(), dataList);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    listView.setItemChecked(initSelectedPosition, true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // 選択状態を要素(checkable)へ反映
            Checkable child = (Checkable) parent.getChildAt(position);
            child.toggle();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

private static class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public TestAdapter(Context context, List<String> dataList) {
        super(context, 0, dataList);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_list_column, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // bindData
        holder.text.setText(getItem(position));
        return convertView;
    }
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've face the same problem as I want to place 4 different radio button in two different linearlayout and these layout will be the child of radio group. To achieve the desire behavior in RadioGroup I have overloaded the addView function

Here is the solution

```
public class AgentRadioGroup extends RadioGroup
{

    public AgentRadioGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AgentRadioGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAdded(View child) {
        if( child instanceof ViewGroup)
        {
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) child;
            for(int i=0; i<viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
            {
                View subChild = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
                if( subChild instanceof ViewGroup )
                {
                    onViewAdded(subChild);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (subChild instanceof RadioButton) {
                        super.onViewAdded(subChild);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (child instanceof RadioButton)
        {
            super.onViewAdded(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's already 20 answers, but dare I say I think I have the best one.

This uses view data binding, so the first thing you'll want to do is add this in your *module's* `build.gradle`.

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Then you can make a layout with your desired view hierarchy, for example:

#### fancy_radio_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable name="title" type="String"/>
        <variable name="description" type="String"/>
        <variable name="checked" type="boolean"/>
        <variable name="buttonId" type="int"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--  clickable=false since we implement the click listener on the whole view  -->
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@{title}"
            android:checked="@{checked}"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@{description}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

This can look however you want, just make sure to set `android:clickable="false"` on the `RadioButton`, and use the data binding variables where needed.

That layout gets handled by this class:

#### FancyRadioGroup.java

```
package com.example.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import com.example.app.FancyRadioButtonBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FancyRadioGroup extends RadioGroup implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final ArrayList<FancyRadioButtonBinding> radioButtons = new ArrayList<>();
    private OnSelectionChangedListener selectionChangedListener;

    public FancyRadioGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FancyRadioGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setOnSelectionChangedListener(OnSelectionChangedListener selectionChangedListener) {
        this.selectionChangedListener = selectionChangedListener;
    }

    public int addOption(String title, String description) {
        // inflate view and get binding
        FancyRadioButtonBinding buttonBinding = FancyRadioButtonBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()), this, true);
        // set title and description
        buttonBinding.setTitle(title);
        buttonBinding.setDescription(description);
        // give the button an id (just use the index)
        buttonBinding.setButtonId(radioButtons.size());
        // set the root view's tag to the binding, so we can get the binding from the view
        View root = buttonBinding.getRoot();
        root.setTag(buttonBinding);
        // set click listener on the whole view, so we can click anywhere
        root.setOnClickListener(this);
        radioButtons.add(buttonBinding);
        // return button id to caller, so they know what was clicked
        return buttonBinding.getButtonId();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (FancyRadioButtonBinding binding : radioButtons) {
                binding.setChecked(v.getTag() == binding);
        }
        if (selectionChangedListener != null) {
            selectionChangedListener.onSelectionChanged(getSelected());
        }
    }

    public int getSelected() {
        for (FancyRadioButtonBinding binding : radioButtons) {
            if (binding.getChecked()) {
                return binding.getButtonId();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public interface OnSelectionChangedListener {
        void onSelectionChanged(int buttonId);
    }

}
```

To use, simply add the `FancyRadioGroup` to your view:

#### activity_foo.xml

```
<com.example.app.FancyRadioGroup android:id="@+id/radio_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And then add your options:

#### FooActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FancyRadioGroup radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    radioGroup.addOption("The First One", "This option is recommended for users who like the number one.");
    radioGroup.addOption("The Second One", "For advanced users. Larger than one.");
    radioGroup.setOnSelectionChangedListener(this::doSomething);
}

private void doSomething(int id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "selected: "+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from implementing that layout structure(`RadioGroup` is in fact a subclass of `LinearLayout`) but you shouldn't. First of all you create a structure 4 levels deep(using another layout structure you could optimize this)  and second, if your `RadioButtons` are not direct children of a `RadioGroup`, *the only one item selected in group* will not work. This means that if you select a `Radiobutton` from that layout and then select another `RadioButton` you'll end up with two `RadioButtons` selected instead of the last selected one.

If you explain what you want to do in that layout maybe I can recommend you an alternative.

Comment: Luksprog, Thanks for your explanation.
If I understand right
if RadioButtons are not direct children of a radio group it will not work.

Comment: @marcoqf73 Yes, to put it more simple, if you have anything in the layout between the `RadioButtons` and the parent `RadioGroup` then this will not work like usual and basically you'll end up with a `LinearLayout` filled with `RadioButtons`.

Comment: There are bunches of reasons to do something like this.  For example you may want to have more control of your layouts than a simple LinearLayout; in my case, I want to make multiple rows of RadioButtons.  Nesting layouts is how pretty much EVERY Android layout works.  Bah, I'm sick of hearing, "You can't do that," while searching for solutions to these UI quirks, which I get about every other day.  :(

Comment: @ScottBiggs I didn't say you can't do that, I said that trying what the user who asked the question will not work. You are free to implement your own layout(but is not that easy to get it right) or use a trick like in this answer of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425569/radiogroup-with-two-columns-which-have-ten-radiobuttons/10425792#10425792 .

Comment: I created a radiogroup class that extended table layout and added features from the radiogroup class.  It works quite well with an unlimited number of columns adding the radio buttons dynamically.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425569/radiogroup-with-two-columns-which-have-ten-radiobuttons/22465700#22465700

Answer (score 1):

My $0.02 based on @infografnet and @lostdev (also thanks @Neromancer for the Compound Button suggestion!)

```
public class AdvRadioGroup {
    public interface OnButtonCheckedListener {
        void onButtonChecked(CompoundButton button);
    }

    private final List<CompoundButton> buttons;
    private final View.OnClickListener onClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setChecked((CompoundButton) v);
        }
    };

    private OnButtonCheckedListener listener;
    private CompoundButton lastChecked;


    public AdvRadioGroup(View view) {
        buttons = new ArrayList<>();
        parseView(view);
    }

    private void parseView(final View view) {
        if(view instanceof CompoundButton) {
            buttons.add((CompoundButton) view);
            view.setOnClickListener(onClick);
        } else if(view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            final ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view;
            for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount();i++) {
                parseView(group.getChildAt(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public List<CompoundButton> getButtons() { return buttons; }

    public CompoundButton getLastChecked() { return lastChecked; }

    public void setChecked(int index) { setChecked(buttons.get(index)); }

    public void setChecked(CompoundButton button) {
        if(button == lastChecked) return;

        for (CompoundButton btn : buttons) {
            btn.setChecked(false);
        }

        button.setChecked(true);

        lastChecked = button;

        if(listener != null) {
            listener.onButtonChecked(button);
        }
    }

    public void setOnButtonCheckedListener(OnButtonCheckedListener listener) { this.listener = listener; }
}
```

Usage (with included listener):

```
AdvRadioGroup group = new AdvRadioGroup(findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW));
group.setOnButtonCheckedListener(new AdvRadioGroup.OnButtonCheckedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onButtonChecked(CompoundButton button) {
        // do fun stuff here!
    }
});
```

Bonus: You can get the last checked button, the list of entire buttons, and you can check any button by index with this!

Comment: great solution! it work for me. only cro you need to asign to the linear layouts inside a new onClick listener because only if you touch the circle of the radiobutton the seleccion changes.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in answers, the solution is a simple custom hack. Here's my minimalistic version in Kotlin.

```
import android.widget.RadioButton

class SimpleRadioGroup(private val radioButtons: List<RadioButton>) {

    init {
        radioButtons.forEach {
            it.setOnClickListener { clickedButton ->
                radioButtons.forEach { it.isChecked = false }
                (clickedButton as RadioButton).isChecked = true
            }
        }
    }

    val checkedButton: RadioButton?
        get() = radioButtons.firstOrNull { it.isChecked }
}
```

then you just need to do something like that in your activity's onCreate or fragment's onViewCreated :

```
SimpleRadioGroup(listOf(radio_button_1, radio_button_2, radio_button_3))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int currentCheckedRadioButton = 0;
    int[] myRadioButtons= new int[6];
    myRadioButtons[0] = R.id.first;
    myRadioButtons[1] = R.id.second;
    //..
    for (int radioButtonID : myRadioButtons) {
        findViewById(radioButtonID).setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (currentCheckedRadioButton != 0)
                    ((RadioButton) findViewById(currentCheckedRadioButton)).setChecked(false);
                currentCheckedRadioButton = v.getId();

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While this maybe an older topic, i would like to quickly share simple hacky code i wrote.. Its not for everyone and could do with some refinement as well..

**The situation to use this code??**
This code is for people who have a layout of the original question or similar, in my case it was as below. This personally was for a Dialog that i was using.

- LinLayout_Main

  - LinLayout_Row1

    - ImageView
    - RadioButton
  - LinLayout_Row2

    - ImageView
    - RadioButton
  - LinLayout_Row3

    - ImageView
    - RadioButton

**What does the code do itself??**
This code will enumerate ever Child of "LinLayout_Main" and for each child that is a "LinearLayout" it will then enumerate that View for any RadioButtons.

Simply it will look the parent "LinLayout_Main" and find any RadioButtons that are in any Child LinearLayouts.

**MyMethod_ShowDialog**
Will show a dialog with a XML layout file while also looking it to set the "setOnClickListener" for each RadioButton it finds

**MyMethod_ClickRadio**
Will loop each RadioButton the same way "MyMethod_ShowDialog" does but instead of setting the "setOnClickListener" it will instead "setChecked(false)" to clear each RadioButton and then as the last step will "setChecked(false)" to the RadioButton that called the click event.

```
public void MyMethod_ShowDialog(final double tmpLat, final double tmpLng) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(actMain);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialogXML);

        final LinearLayout tmpLayMain = (LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.LinLayout_Main);
        if (tmpLayMain!=null) {
            // Perform look for each child of main LinearLayout
            int iChildCount1 = tmpLayMain.getChildCount();
            for (int iLoop1=0; iLoop1 < iChildCount1; iLoop1++){
                View tmpChild1 = tmpLayMain.getChildAt(iLoop1);
                if (tmpChild1 instanceof LinearLayout) {
                    // Perform look for each LinearLayout child of main LinearLayout
                    int iChildCount2 = ((LinearLayout) tmpChild1).getChildCount();
                    for (int iLoop2=0; iLoop2 < iChildCount2; iLoop2++){
                        View tmpChild2 = ((LinearLayout) tmpChild1).getChildAt(iLoop2);
                        if (tmpChild2 instanceof RadioButton) {
                            ((RadioButton) tmpChild2).setOnClickListener(new RadioButton.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    MyMethod_ClickRadio(v, dialog);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Button dialogButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.LinLayout_Save);
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
       dialog.show();
}


public void MyMethod_ClickRadio(View vRadio, final Dialog dDialog) {

        final LinearLayout tmpLayMain = (LinearLayout)dDialog.findViewById(R.id.LinLayout_Main);
        if (tmpLayMain!=null) {
            int iChildCount1 = tmpLayMain.getChildCount();
            for (int iLoop1=0; iLoop1 < iChildCount1; iLoop1++){
                View tmpChild1 = tmpLayMain.getChildAt(iLoop1);
                if (tmpChild1 instanceof LinearLayout) {
                    int iChildCount2 = ((LinearLayout) tmpChild1).getChildCount();
                    for (int iLoop2=0; iLoop2 < iChildCount2; iLoop2++){
                        View tmpChild2 = ((LinearLayout) tmpChild1).getChildAt(iLoop2);
                        if (tmpChild2 instanceof RadioButton) {
                            ((RadioButton) tmpChild2).setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ((RadioButton) vRadio).setChecked(true);
}
```

**There maybe bugs, copied from project and renamed Voids/XML/ID**

You can also run the same type of loop to find out which items are checked

Comment: Were you able to get this to work.  I'm trying to create a radiogroup with sub-linearlayouts that have a radio button next to a regular button.  I couldn't get it to work and [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973613/android-radio-group-oncheckchangedlistener-crashing-app), but was told that radiogroup will crash on any children that are not radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of @Infografnet's solution. It's simple and easy to use.

`RadioGroupHelper group = new RadioGroupHelper(this,R.id.radioButton1,R.id.radioButton2);
group.radioButtons.get(0).performClick(); //programmatically`

Just copy and paste

```
package com.qamar4p.farmer.ui.custom;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class RadioGroupHelper {

    public List<CompoundButton> radioButtons = new ArrayList<>();

    public RadioGroupHelper(RadioButton... radios) {
        super();
        for (RadioButton rb : radios) {
            add(rb);
        }
    }

    public RadioGroupHelper(Activity activity, int... radiosIDs) {
        this(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content),radiosIDs);
    }

    public RadioGroupHelper(View rootView, int... radiosIDs) {
        super();
        for (int radioButtonID : radiosIDs) {
            add((RadioButton)rootView.findViewById(radioButtonID));
        }
    }

    private void add(CompoundButton button){
        this.radioButtons.add(button);
        button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = v -> {
        for (CompoundButton rb : radioButtons) {
            if(rb != v) rb.setChecked(false);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution on Kotlin for custom layout with RadioButton inside.

```
tipInfoContainerFirst.radioButton.isChecked = true

var prevSelected = tipInfoContainerFirst.radioButton
prevSelected.isSelected = true

listOf<RadioButton>(
    tipInfoContainerFirst.radioButton,
    tipInfoContainerSecond.radioButton,
    tipInfoContainerThird.radioButton,
    tipInfoContainerForth.radioButton,
    tipInfoContainerCustom.radioButton
).forEach {
    it.setOnClickListener { _it ->
    if(!it.isSelected) {
        prevSelected.isChecked = false
        prevSelected.isSelected = false
        it.radioButton.isSelected = true
        prevSelected = it.radioButton
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get into the same problem, I have to use Radio button for gender and all were with a picture and a text so I tried to resolve it using following way.

xml file:

```
<RadioGroup
       android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
       android:id="@+id/rgGender"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_below="@id/tvCustomer"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:layout_weight="1">
       <RadioButton
           android:id="@+id/rbMale"
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="60dp"
           android:background="@drawable/male_radio_btn_selector"
           android:button="@null"
           style="@style/RadioButton.Roboto.20sp"/>

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Male"
               style="@style/TextView.RobotoLight.TxtGrey.18sp"
               android:layout_margin="0dp"
               android:textSize="@dimen/txtsize_20sp"/>
       </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:layout_weight="1">
       <RadioButton
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:id="@+id/rbFemale"
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="60dp"
           android:button="@null"
           android:background="@drawable/female_radio_btn_selector"
           style="@style/RadioButton.Roboto.20sp"
           android:textColor="@color/light_grey"/>
           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Female"
               android:layout_margin="0dp"
               style="@style/TextView.RobotoLight.TxtGrey.18sp"
               android:textSize="@dimen/txtsize_20sp"/>
       </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:layout_weight="1">
       <RadioButton
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:id="@+id/rbOthers"
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="60dp"
           android:button="@null"
           android:background="@drawable/other_gender_radio_btn_selector"
           style="@style/RadioButton.Roboto.20sp"/>
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Other"
              android:layout_margin="0dp"
              style="@style/TextView.RobotoLight.TxtGrey.18sp"
              android:textSize="@dimen/txtsize_20sp"/>
      </LinearLayout>
   </RadioGroup>
```

In java file:
I set setOnCheckedChangeListener on all 3 radio buttons and override method as mentioned below and its working fine for me.

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
   switch (compoundButton.getId()){
       case R.id.rbMale:
           if(rbMale.isChecked()){
               rbMale.setChecked(true);
               rbFemale.setChecked(false);
               rbOther.setChecked(false);
           }
           break;
       case R.id.rbFemale:
           if(rbFemale.isChecked()){
               rbMale.setChecked(false);
               rbFemale.setChecked(true);
               rbOther.setChecked(false);
           }
           break;
       case R.id.rbOthers:
           if(rbOther.isChecked()){
               rbMale.setChecked(false);
               rbFemale.setChecked(false);
               rbOther.setChecked(true);
           }
           break;

   }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**MixedCompoundButtonGroup** do it for you!

[MixedCompoundButtonGroup gist](https://gist.github.com/avisper/4a7da16294add0a96a722f6a97c0a5cd)

```
fun setAll() {
    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
        val child = getChildAt(i)
        setCompoundButtonListener(child)
    }
}  


private fun setCompoundButtonListener(view: View?) {
    if (view == null) return
    if (view is CompoundButton) {
        view.setOnCheckedChangeListener(compoundButtonCheckedChangedListener)
    } else if (view is ViewGroup && view !is RadioGroup) { // NOT RadioGroup!
        for (i in 0 until view.childCount) {
            setCompoundButtonListener(view.getChildAt(i))
        }
    }
}

private fun initCompoundButtonListener() {
    compoundButtonCheckedChangedListener = CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, isChecked ->
        setChecked(compoundButton, isChecked)
    }
}

private fun setChecked(compoundButton: CompoundButton, isChecked: Boolean) {
    if (isChecked.not()) return
    if (currentCompoundButton != null) {
        currentCompoundButton!!.isChecked = false
        currentCompoundButton = compoundButton
    } else {
        currentCompoundButton = compoundButton
    }
    checkedChangedListener?.onCheckedChanged(currentCompoundButton!!)
}
```