# How to display a WebView in a RadioButton?

Tags: android, webview, radio-button, latex, mathjax

I need to display Math Formulas instead text in my `RadioButton`.
[Formulas examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/464lE.png)
To display this Math Formulas i am using `MathJax`, but `MathJax` only display the Math Formulas in `WebView`, not in `TextView`.
I tried  to create a `LinearLayout` horizontal for each `RadioButton` + `WebView` and put all of this in a `RadioGroup`, but sadly when i check a `RadioButton` it is always checked, probably the `RadioGroup` doesn't work cause the `LinearLayout`.

Look:

```
    <!--******************************* CUSTOM RADIOGROUP *******************************-->
        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/RadioWebView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rd_group_id">


            <!--******************************* QUESTAO 1 ***********************************-->
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/questao1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/ebRadio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                />

            <io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
                android:id="@+id/webviewQuestao1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                auto:text="\\(x \\over 2\\)"
                auto:engine="MathJax"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_QuestaoTexto"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            </io.github.kexanie.library.MathView>
        </LinearLayout>


            <!--******************************* QUESTAO 2 ***********************************-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/questao2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/ebRadio2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                <io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
                    android:id="@+id/webviewQuestao2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    auto:text="\\(-x \\over 2\\)"
                    auto:engine="MathJax"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_QuestaoTexto"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
                </io.github.kexanie.library.MathView>
            </LinearLayout>


            <!--******************************* QUESTAO 3 ***********************************-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/questao3"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/ebRadio3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   />

                <io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
                    android:id="@+id/webviewQuestao3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    auto:text="\\(x \\sqrt {2}\\)"
                    auto:engine="MathJax"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_QuestaoTexto"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
                </io.github.kexanie.library.MathView>
            </LinearLayout>


            <!--******************************* QUESTAO 4 ***********************************-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/questao4"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/ebRadio4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                <io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
                    android:id="@+id/webviewQuestao4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    auto:text="\\({x \\sqrt {2}}\\over 23^{x+y+z}\\)"
                    auto:engine="MathJax"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_QuestaoTexto"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
                </io.github.kexanie.library.MathView>
            </LinearLayout>


            <!--******************************* QUESTAO 5 ***********************************-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/questao5"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/ebRadio5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     />

                <io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
                    android:id="@+id/webviewQuestao5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    auto:text="\\(y = {{{x \\sqrt {2}}\\over 23^{x+y+z}}-{x \\sqrt {xy+53}}\\over R^{3+y+z}}\\)"
                    auto:engine="MathJax"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_QuestaoTexto"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
                </io.github.kexanie.library.MathView>
            </LinearLayout>


        </RadioGroup>
        <!--******************************* CUSTOM RADIOGROUP *******************************-->
```

And this is the result:
[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRN9F.png)

Someone knows how to display the `WebView` or turn the `RadioButton` uncheckable?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RadioGroup does not allow any ViewGroup as its child. It looks the only way to do this is to use individual radio buttons and then programmically control there on/off states.

Follow this link for more:

[How to group RadioButton from different LinearLayouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461005/how-to-group-radiobutton-from-different-linearlayouts)