# Inflating Nested Layout with RadioButton to a Container

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, radio-group, android-inflate

I have created a layout that will be inflated to a container this layout contain radiobutton

**Problem:** The layout inflated but all the radio button get checked, is this wrong?.

**Layout containing radio button to be inflated in the container.**

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="23dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
   <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Layout for the container**

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Code Inflating the child**

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++){
        LinearLayout child =(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_linear_with_rb,container,false);
        container.addView(child);
    }
```

**Screenshot:**[RadioButton screenshot containing someview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrQlf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the RadioGroup it looks for a RadioButton child only, and because Im using a nested layout that contain the RadioButton the RadioGroup cannot find the RadioButton that is inflated programmatically.

How I solve this problem is with the
https://github.com/worker8/RadioGroupPlus this is a tweak RadioGroup that dig deep on nested layout and find the RadioButton inside.

Answer (score 1):

RadioGroup [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)

> The selection is identified by the unique id of the radio button as defined in the XML layout file.

And looking at your codebase, I see that you don't have an unique Id for your RadioButton.

I made a sample project and tried adding RadioButton's dynamically with unique Ids and it works flawlessly.

```
    RadioGroup container = findViewById(R.id.container);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++){
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
        radioButton.setId(i);
        container.addView(radioButton);
    }
```

There might be a problem of conflicting ids in this case. Maybe an id of 0 is set on some other view. To avoid such confusion I recommend using *View.generateViewId()* to generate an unique id.

*View.generateViewId()* is available only from API >= 17.

**Edit 1**

Please stop using LinearLayout as parent inside your RadioButton layout. A quick fix for you will be changing the RadioButton layout file to

```
<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And changing your Java code to

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++){
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_linear_with_rb,container,false);
    radioButton.setId(i);
    container.addView(radioButton);
}
```

Comment: I have a problem the LinearLayout that is the parent of the RadioButton contains some view, I didn't included it in my question Im sorry.

Comment: Try putting unique ids like the way I'm doing to the LinearLayouts as well.

Comment: I added the screenshot of my radiobutton layout

Comment: I guess there is no direct way of achieving what you're trying to do. This link might be of some use https://stackoverflow.com/a/13273890/2356570

Comment: Add your answer in the question. It will help others.