# Can I have a LinearLayout in a RadioGroup?

Tags: android

I am currently developing a small application, and I need to have two custom `RadioButton` (Man / Woman) like this in this [example](https://github.com/londonappbrewery/Images/blob/master/bmi-calc-demo.gif):

The problem is that I cannot make the frames around the image, because I can not put `LinearLayout` in the `RadioGroup`, otherwise both `RadioButton` are selected ...

Would you have a solution?

Thank you...

Comment: I don't think it is a radiogroup, it is something else like cardview

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're trying to ask, but the second answer here might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461005/how-to-group-radiobutton-from-different-linearlayouts