# How to check radiobuttons using kotlin code while using MVVM architecture?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-mvvm, android-radiogroup

I am using MVVM architecture in my app and there are 4 radiobuttons in a 2*2 grid inside a radiogroup but the the problem is oncheckedChanged is not getting called in viewmodel class, here's the xml code:

```
          <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:checkedButton="@id/singleRadioBtn"
            android:onCheckedChanged="@{viweModel::selectOption}"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                  ></RadioButton>

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <RadioButton

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                   ></RadioButton>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
               ></RadioButton>

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                  ></RadioButton>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RadioGroup>
```

and in viewmodel:

```
 fun selectOption(radioGroup: RadioGroup, id: Int)
    {
        radioGroup.check(id)
    }
```

But the above function is not getting called. So what I am doing wrong here? Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is not with DataBinding - it's rather because you put LinearLayouts inside RadioGroup. Since Radiogroup is a subclass of LinearLayout itself it makes a mess, so in general you'll have to do something additional in code to make it work (but then DataBinding in the case is not so useful), you can look through discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461005/how-to-group-radiobutton-from-different-linearlayouts).

If you try to place RadioButtons just inside RadioGroup (without nested LinearLayouts) I guess your method should be called.

As a workaround you could bind another callback - each RadioButton's `onClick` (setting index of RadioGroup there explicitly):

```
//...........
<RadioButton
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.selectOption(1)}"
></RadioButton>

<Space
     android:layout_width="8dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RadioButton

     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="30dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.selectOption(2)}"
></RadioButton>
//...............
```

**UPDATE**

One of the choices - to make it work according to your current model:

1. To give id to Radiogroup (so it can be used in binding expression)
2. To give ids to RadioButtons
3. To change a little bit method in ViewModel

XML

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    .......>
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.selectOption(radioGroup,v)}" // <- v - is your button
```

ViewModel

```
fun selectOption(radioGroup: RadioGroup, radioButton: View)
{
    radioGroup.check(radioButton.id)
}
```

Comment: can you please display its(@{(v) -> viewModel.selectOption(2)}) viewmodel implementation and what is v here? and how do i uncheck the rest of the buttons?

Comment: literally the best and easy solution for this, thanks

Comment: Actually, there is easier solution. If it is the only task you want in ViewModel, then for that you really don't need ViewModel. You can just set in XML `android:onClick="@{(v) -> radioGroup.check(v.id)}"`.

Comment: this is to be set on radiogroup onclick()? but i think this well check all of the buttons and i want only single button to be selected at a time.

Comment: and also Submit button  click how do i know the current selected button inside viewmodel?

Comment: No, I meant to put this into each RadioButton onClick. But yes - that will not help to get active button in ViewModel

Comment: i think to get activebutton id i have to make one Observable and keep posting the updated id's to it.