# Custom RadioButton with editText

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, android-radiobutton

I implemented a radiobutton with edittext as shown

[image]

I did this by manually placing an `EditText` outside the `RadioGroup`, adjacent to the last `RadioButton` and implemented a logic to get the value of editext when the last `RadioButton` is selected.
Now I want to make a custom `RadioButton` with this functionality that is also compatible with the radio group.
My approach has been to inflate the `EditText` inside the `RadioButton`and then use it in a `RadioGroup` but no luck so far.

Any suggestions with this approach or any different approach are appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461005/how-to-group-radiobutton-from-different-linearlayouts, looks like it would require a custom RadioGroup class, but that solution does work

Comment: To accomplish what you intended, you have to code two custom classes which are RadioButton and RadioGroup. Because default radio group accepts only RadioButton children and you cannot implement custom radioButton containing an edit text by extending default class. Default RadioButton class is a compound button so it is a button and does not accept an edit text. You should go with your current approach to avoid complexity, if you don't use it extensively in your project.