# RadioGroup doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-group, android-event

I want to give the user four choices, the first and second choices on a row and the third and fourth choices on another row. My problem is when the application starts I can select more than one choice, but I don't want that. This is my xml layout:

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgAnswerQuestionChoices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rAnswerQuestonChoic1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rAnswerQuestionChoice2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rAnswerQuestionChoice3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rAnswerQuestionChoice4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "i can't select more than one choice , but i don't want that " - what do you want?  Select two choices, three, four, none?

Comment: you are using radio group it wont allow you to select more than one radiobutton

Comment: no no sorry , i don't want to select more than one choice , i will edit the question

Comment: i mean , i used radio group and i can select more than one choice , where is the wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you place other layouts between the `RadioButtons` and the parent `Radiogroup`(like you did with those `LinearLayouts`) then the mutual exclusion will not work anymore.

To put those `RadioButtons` in a two rows table you could make your own `RadioGroup` which places the `RadioButtons` like you want or you can try to simulate that layout by having two `RadioGroups` that behave as one(for example, [RadioGroup with two columns which have ten RadioButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425569/radiogroup-with-two-columns-which-have-ten-radiobuttons)).

Comment: so what is the solution ? what ever the solution was but i want to keep the first and second choice at one row and the third and fourth choices at another row, thank you for helping

Comment: just one thing please , i did as the link you gave to me , but i have a problem , please see this piece of code ,the radio buttons doesn't appear vertically http://www.mediafire.com/?t4jo313u9rcy9o8

Comment: @Totti I didn't understand what problems you encounter. The two `RadioGroups` from your link should be put in another layout(like a `LinearLayout` with orientation `horizontal`) to form the two rows table. See this link as an example https://gist.github.com/2977860

Answer (score 1):

I know its late but I post it for anybody that face this problem in android. if you use `RadioGroup` in android, you can't put `RadioButtons` anywhere you want except the exact child of your `RadioGroup` with no depth of hierarchy. so if you want to put your `RadioButtons` in a `LinearLayout` or manage it in a grid, buttons don't act like their belongs to the group (they will stay checked if the user check another `RadioButton` in the group).

#### My solution

I wrote a class named `RadioGroupCheckListener.java` and simply use this line of code to declare a group:

```
RadioGroupCheckListener.makeGroup(radioButton1, radioButton2, radioButton3, radioButton4);
```

you can find `RadioGroupCheckListener.java` in my github [RadioGroupCheckListener](https://github.com/farzinlize/RadioGroupCheckListener)

```
import android.widget.CompoundButton;


public class RadioGroupCheckListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private CompoundButton[] allies;

    /**
     * public generator - indicate allies
     * @param allies all other buttons in the same RadioGroup
     */
    public RadioGroupCheckListener(CompoundButton... allies){
        this.allies = allies;
    }

    /**
     * listener for a button to turn other allies unchecked when it turn checked
     * @param buttonView change check occur with this button
     * @param isChecked result of changing
     */
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
            for (CompoundButton aly : allies) {
                aly.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * inner private function to remove one element from Buttons array
     * @param buttons all the buttons in RadioGroup
     * @param me the index that we want to remove from array
     * @return an array of CompoundButtons except the index of me
     */
    private static CompoundButton[] exceptMe(CompoundButton[] buttons, int me){
        CompoundButton[] result = new CompoundButton[buttons.length-1];
        for(int i=0,j=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
            if(i==me){
                continue;
            }
            result[j]=buttons[i];
            j++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * static function to create a RadioGroup
     * if a button turn to checked state all other buttons is group turn unchecked
     * @param buttons the buttons that we want to act like RadioGroup
     */
    public static void makeGroup(CompoundButton... buttons){
        for(int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
            buttons[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroupCheckListener(exceptMe(buttons, i)));
        }
    }
}
```