# RadioButtons inside same RadioGroup but both buttons can be selected

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, radio-group

I have two `RadioButtons` inside the same `RadioGroup`. But beside each `RadioButton` i want an `ImageButton` (info). Therefore my code is as below:

```
<RadioGroup>
    <LinearLayout>     //Horizontal 
        <RadioButton/>
        <ImageButton/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>     //Horizontal 
        <RadioButton/>
        <ImageButton/>
    </LinearLayout>
<RadioGroup/>
```

But now the problem I am facing is fairly simple, both RadioButtons can be selected. I want only one to get selected at a time.

Plz ignore any typos. Bound to post this from phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/11168605/4395530

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did find a solution which worked for me because I had very few `RadioButtons`.

I set an OnClickListener() for each `RadioButton` and set other unselected.

```
final RadioButton a1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a1);
final RadioButton a2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a2);
    a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            a2.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
    a2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            a1.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'll think I'll use this same approach. But since I have a lot of options, what I'll do is track the last radioButton selected and within OnClickListener() implement `lastRadioButtonSelected.setChecked(false)`. I guess have to strong-arm Android SDK to get stuff done on time !

Answer (score 1):

`RadioGroup`s are `LinearLayout`s themselves and only support `RadioButton`s as direct children. You can see this behavior [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/RadioGroup.java#RadioGroup.PassThroughHierarchyChangeListener.onChildViewAdded%28android.view.View%2Candroid.view.View%29).

What you are trying to do is not possible like this, since you wrap your `RadioButton` in a `LinearLayout`.

You have 2 possibilities: You can either copy the code and make your own `RadioGroup`,
or you can `extend RadioButton` and just change its appearence by applying your custom layout *there*, inside your `RadioButton`.

Answer (score 0):

RadioGroup does not allow any ViewGroup as its child . You will have to use drawableRight attribute.

Comment: I guess you didn't get the question. I would ask you to read it once again.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use radiobuttons only the child of a radio group
2. if u dont want this then use my code and remove radiogroup u can use custom radio buttons

   ```
     final RadioButton a1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a1);
    final RadioButton a2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a2);
    a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         a2.setChecked(false);                    
         a1.setChecked(true);

     }
        });
      a2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       a1.setChecked(false);
       a2.setChecked(true);

   }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

RadioButton rbOne, rbTwo, rbThree, rbFour;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rbOne = findViewById(R.id.rbOne);
    rbTwo = findViewById(R.id.rbTwo);
    rbThree = findViewById(R.id.rbThree);
    rbFour = findViewById(R.id.rbFour);

    rbOne.setOnClickListener(this);
    rbTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
    rbThree.setOnClickListener(this);
    rbFour.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == rbOne) {
        isChecked(1);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rbOne.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (view == rbTwo) {
        isChecked(2);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rbTwo.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (view == rbThree) {
        isChecked(3);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rbThree.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (view == rbFour) {
        isChecked(4);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rbFour.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void isChecked(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            rbTwo.setChecked(false);
            rbThree.setChecked(false);
            rbFour.setChecked(false);
            break;
        case 2:
            rbOne.setChecked(false);
            rbThree.setChecked(false);
            rbFour.setChecked(false);
            break;
        case 3:
            rbOne.setChecked(false);
            rbTwo.setChecked(false);
            rbFour.setChecked(false);
            break;
        case 4:
            rbOne.setChecked(false);
            rbTwo.setChecked(false);
            rbThree.setChecked(false);
            break;
    }
}

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgMemberShip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="One Time"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:text="One Time"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbThree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="One Time"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbFour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:text="One Time"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score -1):

UPDATED: I think this will help you. I had the same issue.

```
<LinearLayout> //Horizontal
    <LinearLayout>//Vertical
        <ImageButton/>
        <ImageButton/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>//Vertical
        <RadioGroup> //Vertical
            <RadioButton/>
            <RadioButton/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBZTa.png) [This is how it will appear in the end]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this helps because you don't show how to put an `ImageButton` beside this `RadioButtons`

Comment: You don't need the `<LinearLayout>//Vertical` just replace that with the RadioGroup since a RadioGroup is already a layout. However, I imagine  this approach is a PITA to line-up the radio buttons and images

Comment: I re-updated the Answer matching your needs. Can you please reconsider the upvote? This way when you click on radiobutton, because they are under radiogroup, it will swap the clicked variable.