# android radio Button is not deselection when another radio button is selected

Tags: android, xml, landscape-portrait

I have a layout that has multiple radio buttons in different rows ( two columns of radio buttons separated by table rows) and when i select one of them,the previous selected doesn't get deselected.I keep selecting all the other's and none gets deselected . This only happens because of the rows as the straight layout works just fine .what am i doing wrong ?

> ```
>    <RadioGroup
>     android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
>     android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
>     android:orientation="vertical"/>
>     <TableRow>
> <RadioButton
>     android:id="@+id/miliToCentimeters"
>     android:layout_width="258dp"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
>     android:checked="true"
>     android:clickable="false"
>     android:text="@string/milimetersToCentimeters"
>     android:textSize="13sp" />
>     <RadioButton
>         android:id="@+id/inchesToFoothesToFoot"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:text="@string/inchesToFoot"         
>         android:textSize="13sp" />
>      </TableRow>
>        <TableRow>
>     <RadioButton
>         android:id="@+id/centiToMeters"
>         android:layout_width="255dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
>         android:text="@string/centemetersToMeters"
>         android:textSize="13sp" />
>     <RadioButton
>         android:id="@+id/inchesToYardsesToYards"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
>         android:text="@string/inchesToYards"
>         android:textSize="13sp" />
>     </TableRow>
>       <TableRow>
>  <RadioButton
>      android:id="@+id/miliToMetersiToMeters"
>      android:layout_width="255dp"
>      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
>      android:text="@string/milimetersToMeters"
>      android:textSize="13sp" />
>        <RadioButton
>          android:id="@+id/feetToYardsetToYards"
>            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>            android:layout_height="match_parent"
>            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
>            android:text="@string/feetToYards"
>            android:textSize="13sp" />
>        </TableRow>
>          <TableRow>
>     <RadioButton
>        android:id="@+id/metersToKiloersToKilo"
>         android:layout_width="255dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
>         android:text="@string/metersToKilometers"
>         android:textSize="13sp" />
>     <RadioButton
>         android:id="@+id/feetToMilesetToMiles"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
>         android:text="@string/feetToMiles"
>         android:textSize="13sp"/>
>     </TableRow>
>       <TableRow>
>     <RadioButton
>         android:id="@+id/yardsToMilesdsToMiles"
>         android:layout_width="255dp"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
>         android:text="@string/yardsToMiles"
>         android:textSize="13sp" />
>     </TableRow>
> </RadioGroup>
> ```

Comment: When you allow single RadioButton Selection then your RadioButton must direct child of RadioGroup otherwise you have to manually handle each RadioButton selection and deselection.

Comment: You are closing the `RadioGroup` with `/>`. You need the closing tag after the buttons in that group

Comment: thanks guys but so how do i direct the radio buttons as children of radio group?

Comment: @codeMagic is right this is what you need to remove />

Comment: What happens if you simply remove the `/` in your `RadioGroup` as Zoain said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code for selecting single radio button at a time. You should close the radio group only after all the radio button declared inside of the radio group.

```
 <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/miliToCentimeters"
        android:layout_width="258dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="@string/milimetersToCentimeters"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/inchesToFoothesToFoot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/inchesToFoot"         
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/centiToMeters"
            android:layout_width="255dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:text="@string/centemetersToMeters"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/inchesToYardsesToYards"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:text="@string/inchesToYards"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

         <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/miliToMetersiToMeters"
         android:layout_width="255dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
         android:text="@string/milimetersToMeters"
         android:textSize="13sp" />
           <RadioButton
             android:id="@+id/feetToYardsetToYards"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
               android:text="@string/feetToYards"
               android:textSize="13sp" />

        <RadioButton
           android:id="@+id/metersToKiloersToKilo"
            android:layout_width="255dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:text="@string/metersToKilometers"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/feetToMilesetToMiles"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:text="@string/feetToMiles"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/yardsToMilesdsToMiles"
            android:layout_width="255dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:text="@string/yardsToMiles"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: right i know that's in a manner in which all radio buttons will be one underneath another and so on but my goal is to have two columns in landscape display so i dont have to scroll down to see them all ? this is why i had table rows in them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425569/radiogroup-with-two-columns-which-have-ten-radiobuttons hope this link will help.