# How to align Radio Group items in square shape

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to align RadioButtons inside RadioGroup in square shape. Like two radio buttons in one row and two more radio buttons below them in a second row. I achived it by putting two seperate linearlayouts in RadioGroup but then it is impossible to access to the RadioButtons from RadioGroup's id. 
How can i do this?

Comment: You Can find the Answer in [this][1]link 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425569/radiogroup-with-two-columns-which-have-ten-radiobuttons

Comment: I could do this by setting on checkchanged listener on each radio Button too. But i want to know if there is any trick i can do in xml to make that possible.

Comment: I dont think such a trick possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RadioGroup with two columns which have ten RadioButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425569/radiogroup-with-two-columns-which-have-ten-radiobuttons)

Answer (score 1):

I found something which might me helpful [here](http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-radiogroup.html)  - if you want to use Linear Layout.

You can also use Grid Layout but from what I know, you have to extend GridLayout or RadioGroup. This issue was addressed in a lot of questions here on Stack Overflow, try searching for some. Please post some code after reading, maybe we could help more then.