# Regarding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381560/how-to-group-a-3x3-grid-of-radio-buttons

Tags: android, radio-button, grouping

I tried to use the code provided as the first answer on the website that appears in the title. I can't make it work, although I tried to modify it. The problem is that when I check a radio button other than the first radio button, they both stay checked.

Question is: when do the addView methods get called?

Also, here is my version of the code, I hope somebody can show me my mistakes:

```
public class ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout extends TableLayout  implements     OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout";
private ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout radGroup;
private RadioButton activeRadioButton;

/** 
 * @param context
 */
public ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 */
public ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
    radGroup = (ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout) findViewById(R.id.radGroup1);
    int activeRadioButtonId = radGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId(v);
    Log.i(TAG,"FIRST " + activeRadioButtonId);
//       if (activeRadioButtonId != -1 && activeRadioButton != null ) {
//           activeRadioButton.setChecked(false);
//       }
    rb.setChecked(true);
    //activeRadioButton = rb;
    if (activeRadioButtonId != -1 && activeRadioButton != null ) {
        activeRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(activeRadioButtonId);
        activeRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    }
    else
        Log.i(TAG,"" + activeRadioButton + "  " + activeRadioButtonId);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.TableLayout#addView(android.view.View, int,   android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)
 */
@Override
public void addView(View child, int index,
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, index, params);
    setChildrenOnClickListener((TableLayout)child);
}


/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.TableLayout#addView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)
 */
@Override
public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, params);
    setChildrenOnClickListener((TableLayout)child);
}


private void setChildrenOnClickListener(TableLayout tl) {
    final int c = tl.getChildCount();
    for (int i=0; i < c; i++) {
        final View v = tl.getChildAt(i);
        if ( v instanceof TableRow ) {
            final int c1 = ((TableRow) v).getChildCount();
            for (int j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
               View v1 = ((TableRow) v).getChildAt(j);
               if (v1 instanceof RadioButton)
                   v1.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
}

public int getCheckedRadioButtonId(View v) {
    if ( activeRadioButton != null ) {
        return activeRadioButton.getId();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just modify setChildrenOnClickListener:

```
 private void setChildrenOnClickListener(TableRow tr) {
    final int c = tr.getChildCount();
    for (int i=0; i < c; i++) {
        final View v = tr.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof RadioButton) {
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            if (((RadioButton) v).isChecked())
                activeRadioButton = (RadioButton) v;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked while ago, but anyway I think i know the answer..
The issue you're experiening is because you have more radioButtons with no, or same ID. You need to set them different id's in order for them to work.

Hope this will help someone.