# how can we arrange radio group's button as we want. I want 2 radio buttons in a row and other two radio buttons in next row.

Tags: android, radio-button, android-radiogroup

how can we arrange radio group's button as we want.. i don't want to arrange horizontally or vertically.. i want 2 radio buttons in a row and other two radio buttons in next row.. please help thank you in advance...

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tt5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
            android:background="#fff" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icongender" />
            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radiogrp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/student"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="\t\tStudent"
                    android:textColor="#616161" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/buisness"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                    android:text="\t\tBuisness"
                    android:textColor="#616161" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/entertainment"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                    android:text="\t\tEntertainment"
                    android:textColor="#616161" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/others"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                    android:text="\t\tOthers"
                    android:textColor="#616161" />

            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
```

my xml code is above.. this shows me 4 radio buttons in one column but i want 2 radio buttons in one row and other two in next row.
please help thank you in advance

Comment: RadioGroup inherits from LinearLayout. As such, you have **2** possible arrangements: `horizontal` or `vertical`.

Comment: There are work around to achieve what he is looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381560/how-to-group-a-3x3-grid-of-radio-buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make each two `RadioButton`s in one `LinearLayout`which has an `Horizontal`orientation. Or you can use `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to find a way to have the RadioGroup work with a custom layout.
With these keywords you should be able to find more info.

This question seems to be what you are looking for: [Android: custom layout for Radio Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206979/android-custom-layout-for-radio-group)