# RadioButton in multirow in single RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button

I need to create design like radiobutton in multi-row in single radiogroup like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yixw1.png) .

I am using  `android:orientation="horizontal"`

layout.xml

```
 <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="option1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="option2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="option3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="option4" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="option5" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="option6" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is possible.
You will have to subclass TableLayout and add the radio buttons programmatically

here is the link

refer this [MATRIX RADIO BUTTONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381560/how-to-group-a-3x3-grid-of-radio-buttons)

For screen width

[Screen Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

Comment: I am using same but I added three radiobutton in single tablerow but its not appear because small width of screen, is it possible to set item in single according to screen width automatically

Comment: I had used it before. And it works on the small screen size also.

Comment: it is working but I have to fix number of item in row, but I want automatic to screen width like as small screen then 3 item in one row, large screen then 4 item in one row, xtra large then 5 item in one row..

Comment: For that you will have to define your parameters . You can get screen width by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions

Answer (score 0):

parent can be any like linear horizontal or relative(i'd prefer Linear Horizontal), inside that 3 TableRow childs,within each tableRow your RadioButtons. something like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <RadioGroup>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Radio1"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Radio2"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Radio3"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radio4"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radio5"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radio6"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <RadioGroup>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radio1"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radio2"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radio3"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radio4"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radio5"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radio6"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: it is working but I have to fix number of item in row, but I want automatic to screen width like as small screen then 3 item in one row, large screen then 4 item in one row, xtra large then 5 item in one row..

Comment: this is not working in radiogroup, if I check any radiobutton then other radiobutton doesn't unchecked automatically