# How to add Android RadioGroup inside GridLayout

Tags: android

When I tried to add multiple radio buttons which are inside radio group tag to grid layout it's take the behavior of vertical linear layout.

Here's my code.

Radio group functionality works fine.(ability to check only one radio button at time)

```
<GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/main_linear2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:useDefaultMargins="true">

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/check_sunday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="  Sunday" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/check_monday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Monday" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/check_Tuesday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tuesday" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/check_Wednsday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Wednsday" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/check_Thursday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Thursday" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/check_Friday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Friday" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/check_Saturday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Saturday" />

            </RadioGroup>

        </GridLayout>
```

Comment: Fix the radio group height and width to some specific value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group a 3x3 grid of radio buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381560/how-to-group-a-3x3-grid-of-radio-buttons)

Comment: `RadioGroup` is a subclass of `LinearLayout`. Hence, the `RadioButton`s are aligned vertically or horizontally. If you want them in a grid, you can create yourself a custom `GridLayout` subclass that mimics the `RadioGroup` functionality. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2381560/4034572) for some solutions. I've posted [my own custom `GridLayout` subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55422560/4034572) there.