# How to allign 2x2 radio buttons into a group in android

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to android please let me know what I have made wrong, I have added a radio group and next added Gridlayout to align radio buttons in 2x2 form of matrix, it aligned good, but problem is that it is not deselecting previously selected options when I select any radio button. How can I achieve this ?

```
All radio buttons are getting selected. None of them are deselecting upon changing selection of radio button. Please suggest me any approach.

Thanks
```

[image: Please check attached image for reference]

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radOption1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radOption2"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radOption3"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radOption4"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:padding="5dp" />

    </GridLayout>
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RadioGroup` is basically a `LinearLayout` within which you can align your `RadioButtons`. It's not like a generic `layout` that can store anything (`GridLayout` in your example) and it will handle any `RadioButtons` that you will put down in the hierarchy.

TLDR: `RadioGroup` lets you align your `RadioButtons` horizontally or vertically - it's a `LinearLayout`.

The thing you need to do is described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381560/how-to-group-a-3x3-grid-of-radio-buttons).