# How can I create A radiogroup 2x2?

Tags: android, radio-button, kotlin, android-radiogroup

Hello I want to create a radiogroup 2x2 so I achieved to do this using two radiogroup. But the problem is right now I can select two radiobutton instead of only one.. How can I try to do this ?

I precise I use kotlin to develop.

Thank you !

Comment: There's no such a thing. RadioGroup inherits from LinearLayout and therefore can be **either** vertical **or** horizontal.

Comment: I want to create a 2x2 Radiobuttons ! I think it exists obviously !

Comment: **Not in a single RadioGroup, oviously!** You are free to set a grid of 2*2 RadioButtons. But then you won't have the "mutual exclusivity" given by a RadioGroup.

Comment: I think using two `RadioGroup`s should allow you to choose one `RadioButton` in each group

Comment: Yes, but 2 RadioButtons would be contemporarily selected.

Comment: Ok thank you ! I tried to do one radiogroup but it is not 2x2 it is vertical or horizontal unfortunately ...

Comment: Because it inherits from LinearLayout, as I said.

Comment: I tried a tablelayout but it is the same problem... :/

Comment: Because it is not a RadioGroup. This is the only container which gives you the exclusivity. And can only be vertical **OR** horizontal. Not both. As an alternative, you can write your own ViewGroup. But your current experience doesn't allow you to.

Comment: It helps me a lot...

Comment: Look into RadioGroup android source project code, then you can play with the layout and controls according to your needs.
P.S. Downvoter please leave a message as to why this post should not be on SOF.

Comment: Thank you Talha :)

Comment: Be respectful, kid!

Comment: And who judged you? I just said that you don't have enough experience to make your own ViewGroup. Your question proofs it.

Answer (score 0):

here you have a very similar question [gridlayout 3x3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381560/how-to-group-a-3x3-grid-of-radio-buttons)
Because you can't do want you want trivialy, you should to acept 1 of the answers of the question above. What i did:

```
public class GRadioGroup {

    List<RadioButton> radios = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();

    /**
     * Constructor, which allows you to pass number of RadioButton instances,
     * making a group.
     *
     * @param radios
     *            One RadioButton or more.
     */
    public GRadioGroup(RadioButton... radios) {
        super();

        for (RadioButton rb : radios) {
            this.radios.add(rb);
            rb.setOnClickListener(onClick);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor, which allows you to pass number of RadioButtons
     * represented by resource IDs, making a group.
     *
     * @param activity
     *            Current View (or Activity) to which those RadioButtons
     *            belong.
     * @param radiosIDs
     *            One RadioButton or more.
     */
    public GRadioGroup(View activity, int... radiosIDs) {
        super();

        for (int radioButtonID : radiosIDs) {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)activity.findViewById(radioButtonID);
            if (rb != null) {
                this.radios.add(rb);
                rb.setOnClickListener(onClick);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This occurs everytime when one of RadioButtons is clicked,
     * and deselects all others in the group.
     */

    public void addRadioButtonsToGroup(RadioButton rb){
        radios.add(rb);
        rb.setOnClickListener(onClick);
    }

    OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // let's deselect all radios in group
            for (RadioButton rb : radios) {

                ViewParent p = rb.getParent();
                if (p.getClass().equals(RadioGroup.class)) {
                    // if RadioButton belongs to RadioGroup,
                    // then deselect all radios in it
                    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) p;
                    rg.clearCheck();
                } else {
                    // if RadioButton DOES NOT belong to RadioGroup,
                    // just deselect it
                    rb.setChecked(false);
                }
            }

            // now let's select currently clicked RadioButton
            if (!v.getClass().equals(RadioButton.class)) {
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
                rb.setChecked(true);
            }

        }
    };

    /**
     *
     ** Returns the Id of the radio button that is checked or -1 if none are checked
     *
     * @return
     */
    public int getCheckedRadioButtonId() {
        int checkedId = -1;
        // Loop each radio button
        for (RadioButton rb : radios) {
            if (rb.isChecked())
                return rb.getId();
        }
        return checkedId;
    }

    public void setCheckedRadioButton(int pos) {
        // let's deselect all radios in group
        for (RadioButton rb : radios) {

            ViewParent p = rb.getParent();
            if (p.getClass().equals(RadioGroup.class)) {
                // if RadioButton belongs to RadioGroup,
                // then deselect all radios in it
                RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) p;
                rg.clearCheck();
            } else {
                // if RadioButton DOES NOT belong to RadioGroup,
                // just deselect it
                rb.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
        radios.get(pos).setChecked(true);
    }


    public void setCheckedRadioButtonDefault() {
        radios.get(0).setChecked(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void finalize() {
        radios.clear();
    }

}
```

i need add radiobuttons programtically so make my radiobutton.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_right_rests_columns"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_left_rest_column"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

</RadioButton>
```

And for adding (this is in a fragment):

```
    GRadioGroup gr = new GRadioGroup();
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.radiobutton, null);//initialize and set content
radioButton.setText("HEY")
// And all the settings you want like position ...
//finally
 gr.addRadioButtonsToGroup(radioButton);
```

Disadvantages? you have to handle the selected radiogroup with bundle or intents  if the activity/fragment/whatever was destroyed.

Hope help you!